# Handling Recursive Function With setTimeout In A Synchronous Fashion

Tags: javascript

I have the following function and would like to be able to call another function outside of this function and have it run only once this function has completed. I know the setTimeout is what is causing the asynchronous behavior. I've tried promises, but can't figure out how to use the promise in combination with the setTimeout and recursive action.

The basic idea of this function is that it takes a time, we'll say 10 seconds and counts down to 0. Once the countdown reaches zero, then, ideally the next function would run. The setTimeout is used to recursively call the function every 1 second (1000 milliseconds)

```
const countDown = () => {
    if (seconds > 0) displayTime(seconds, 'second', '--');
    else if (minutes > 0) {
        displayTime(minutes, 'minute', '--');
        displayTime(59, 'second');
    }
    else if (hours > 0) {
        displayTime(hours, 'hour', '--');
        displayTime(59, 'minute');
    }

    seconds = parseInt(secondTwo.innerHTML + secondOne.innerHTML);
    minutes = parseInt(minuteTwo.innerHTML + minuteOne.innerHTML);
    hours = parseInt(hourTwo.innerHTML + hourOne.innerHTML);

    if (seconds === 0 && minutes === 0 && hours === 0) {
        audio.play();
        endTimer();
    }

    countDownId = setTimeout(() => {
        countDown();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions or need any clarity! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your HTML too so your code can be interacted with?

Comment: It's unclear what "call another function in a synchronous manner" means. You already call two functions when the countdown reaches zero, so what kind of functionality are you looking for exactly?

Comment: @JJJ After calling this countDown function I would like to be able to call another function outside of this function that runs only once the countDown is complete.

Comment: @CertainPerformance The HTML is created by the JavaScript. You are welcome to look at it on GitHub. github.com/jase-languasco/timer

Comment: @JJJ I also revised my question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe countdown could be simpler if you pass in hours, minutes and seconds and a callback update function. Countdown will call this function every second with values for hours, minutes and seconds left.

Countdown can return a promise that will resolve when countdown is finished:

```js
const later = time => new Promise(
  resolve=>setTimeout(
    ()=>resolve(),
    time
  )
);
const getHours = timeLeft => Math.floor(timeLeft/3600000);
const getMinutes = timeLeft => Math.floor((timeLeft%3600000)/60000);
const getSeconds = timeLeft => Math.floor((timeLeft%60000)/1000);
const countDown = (hours,minutes,seconds) => updateFunction => {
  const start = Date.now();
  const total = (hours*3600000)+(minutes*60000)+(seconds*1000);
  const recur = () => {
    const timePassed = Date.now() - start;
    if(timePassed>=total){
      updateFunction(0,0,0);//call your callback
      return Promise.resolve("what you want to return");//resolve the returned promise to a value
    }
    const secondsLeft = getSeconds(total-timePassed);
    const minutesLeft = getMinutes(total-timePassed);
    const hoursLeft = getHours(total-timePassed);
    if(minutesLeft<0){
      debugger;
    }
    //call your callback
    updateFunction(
      hoursLeft,
      minutesLeft,
      secondsLeft
    );
    return later(1000)
    .then(
      ()=>recur()//recursively call itself
    )
  }
  return recur();
}
countDown(0,2,0)(
  (h,m,s)=>console.log("hours:",h,"minutes:",m,"seconds:",s)
)
.then(
  ()=>console.log("countdown is done")
);
```